# maximum update depth exceeded with a this.setState in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to incremente a variable "this.state.id". but when i'm trying to do that, i have the error

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Basically, my code is like that

```
state={
    visibleModal: null,
    data:[],
    id: 0,
    
  }


  checkId() {
    this.setState({id: this.state.id + 1})
    return (this.state.id);
  }
```

In render ()

```
   <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      style={styles.container}
      renderItem={this.RenderLayout}
      numColumns="1"
      extraData={this.state}
      id={this.checkId(this.state.id)}
    />
```

But i don't understand why i'm having This error. I already tried to just incremente in the function "this.renderLayout", but i have the same mistake.
Anyone have an idea why i have that ? Or maybe a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clore Nora, you make a minor mistake use arrow function

your code

```
   <FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  style={styles.container}
  renderItem={this.RenderLayout}
  numColumns="1"
  extraData={this.state}
  id={this.checkId(this.state.id)}
/>
```

update by this

```
   <FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  style={styles.container}
  renderItem={this.RenderLayout}
  numColumns="1"
  extraData={this.state}
  id={()=>this.checkId(this.state.id)}
/>
```

and checkId function use like this

```
  checkId=()=> {
this.setState((prevState)=>({id: prevState.id + 1}));
```

}